# iOS 7 popover covers progressbar and barbuttonItem tint color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have a problem on my navigation bar.
`UIBarButtonItem` `tintColor` is orange, but when I present popover, `barButtonItem` `tintColor` changes to lightGray. Navigation bar tint color is whiteColor. I need to leave orange color after popover presents. 
Can someone help me? Thank you!

EDIT 1

i make selectable barButtonItem and i have subclass of UIBarButtonItem:

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    _selected = selected;
    if (selected) {
        self.tintColor = self.selectedColor;
    } else {
        self.tintColor = self.defaultColor;
    }
}

-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action defaultColor:(UIColor *)defaultColor {
    self = [super initWithImage:image style:style target:target action:action];
    if (self) {
        self.tintColor = defaultColor;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action defaultColor:(UIColor *)defaultColor {
    self = [super initWithTitle:title style:style target:target action:action];
    if (self) {
        self.tintColor = defaultColor;
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT 2

Thanx Warren Burton for answer, solution is:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is iOS 7 "Normal" . It tells your user that the button is not currently part of your active UI.

If you wish to bypass this normal convention you can subclass UIBarButtonItem and override

`- (void)tintColorDidChange`

just leave an empty implementation.

```
- (void)tintColorDidChange {
   //nothing to see here, move along
}
```

when a popover presents the presenting view goes to tintMode `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed` so even when you provide another color that color gets greyed-out (desaturated?) by the system.

which is why you need to overide `tintColorDidChange` to block that happening.

from the docs...

> When this property’s value is UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed, the
>   value of the tintColor property is modified to provide a dimmed
>   appearance.

Comment: i have edited my question. I need to change tintColor when i press bar button, but when popover presents - i need to prevent colour changing

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by changing the color of the bar button system item png file in an external editor, including that image to the project and loading it via

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButtonBarTrashBlack"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myAction)];
```

I have found the internal system image using the helpful [UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor).

I have edited the color of the artwork using the free software [GIMP](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html).

Answer (score 0):

It does look like an Apple bug, and you should enter a bug on it with bug reporter. That said, I can give you a relatively painless workaround: add this code to your RecipetTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Recipe Book";

    UIBarButtonItem *it = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:NULL];
    UIImage * btBack_30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btBack_30"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
    [it setBackButtonBackgroundImage:btBack_30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = it;
}
```

EDIT: You can dup this bug if interested, the more bugs referencing it the more likely apple will fix it:

Summary: Setting the UIBarButtonItem appearance proxy for the back bar button item does not have any affect until the second appearance of the button.

Steps to Reproduce: In appDelegate, before anything has appeared, add these statements:

```
UIImage * gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar_44"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
 UIImage * gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar_32"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
 // Set the background image for all UINavigationBars [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Expected Results: When a viewController is first pushed, its back button has the image in it.

Actual Results: First time it appears, there is no image. Push the view again and its there. Actually it does appear when you click on the button the very first time, but not when the button first appears.

Version: Xcode 5.0.1, iOS 7.0.3

Notes: Adding this in the root view controller of the navigation controller makes it work:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Recipe Book";
 UIBarButtonItem *it = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:NULL]; 
UIImage * btBack_30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btBack_30"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
 [it setBackButtonBackgroundImage:btBack_30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = it;  
}
```

Happy Coding!!!